# The sum of the squares of $5$ consecutive primes is again prime. True for infinite many quintuples?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

Let $(p,q,r,s,t)$ be a quintuple of consecutive primes.

> Are there infinite many such tuples such that $$p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2+t^2$$ is prime again ?

Motivation :

- $p^2$ is never prime
- $p^2+q^2$ is even for $p>2$
- $p^2+q^2+r^2$ is divisble by $3$ for $p>3$
- $p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2$ is even for $p>2$.

So, the smallest possible case is $5$ squares.

The following table, calculated by PARI/GP has the following meaning :

- The first column stands for the exponent $n$ in $10^n$,
- The second number is the number of primes below $10^n$
- The third column is the number of primes $p$ below $10^n$ such that the above property is satisfied.

> ```
> ? for(n=1,9,a=0;forprime(p=1,10^n,q=nextprime(p+1);r=nextprime(q+1);s=nextprime(
> r+1);t=nextprime(s+1);if(isprime(p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2+t^2)==1,a=a+1));print(n,"   ",p
> rimepi(10^n),"    ",a))
> 1   4    2
> 2   25    8
> 3   168    36
> 4   1229    258
> 5   9592    1637
> 6   78498    11129
> 7   664579    80041
> 8   5761455    603517
> 9   50847534    4706649
> ?
> ```

A large example is $p=10^{100}+9631$

Comment: (+1), i think there are infinitely many prime of such form, i hope the proof is not too hard.

Comment: Clearly the $5$ primes should be odd and it is nice that the first example of consecutive primes  $$3^2+5^2+7^2+11^2+13^2=373$$, prime and this is so for the second example  $$5^2+7^2+11^2+13^2+17^2=653$$, prime too. But the third example fails because $$7^2+11^2+13^2+17^2+19^2=989=23\cdot43$$

Comment: @Ahmad: I do not have any hope that the proof, if possible, will be easy. Regards.

Comment: Even larger possible values for $p$ are $\color\red {10^{300}+178449}$ and $\color\red {10^{500}+7206861}$

Comment: Every integer $x>3$ with the property that the polynomials $$x,x+4,x+6,x+10,x+12,5x^2+64x+296$$ are simultaneously prime is a quintuple of the desired form because the primes $x,x+4,x+6,x+10,x+12$ must be consecutive ($x+2$ and $x+8$ must be divisble by $3$) and we have $$x^2+(x+4)^2+(x+6)^2+(x+10)^2+(x+12)^2=5x^2+64x+296$$ The generaized bunyakovsky conjecture implies that infinite such many $x$ exist which implies the conjecture.

Comment: The numbers $x$ below $10^7$ are : $$97\ 16057\ 43777\ 402757\ 626617\ 2470327\ 2535097\ 3076387\ 3224857\ 4487797\ 4543237\ 4693687\ 4956817\ 5327887\ 6250417\ 6561007\ 7079707\ 7187767\ 8773147$$

Comment: A large possible $x$ is $$\large \color\green {10^{20}+146\ 735\ 187}$$

Comment: @Peter: OK on $5x^2+64x+296$ could give infinitely many primes maybe but what about  the five numbers $x,x+4,x+6,x+10,x+12$ can be consecutive primes? Furthermore either $x+4,x+6$ and $x+10,x+12$ should be twins in this weird circumstance. Very remote or improbable I think. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Nevertheless , it is conjectured that there are infinite many such $x$, of course this conjecture is open because its truth would imply the still open twin-prime-conjecture. The quintuple $x,x+4,x+6,x+10,x+12$ is also called a "prime constellation". For such prime constellations, there is statistical evidence that there are infinite many $n$-tuples.

Comment: @Piquito What I wanted to point out, that there is a conjecture that implies a much stronger claim than the claim given in the question. Maybe the much weaker claim in the question can be proven...

Comment: I found three possible values for $x$ above $10^{30}$ : $$10^{30}+8\ 547\ 295\ 047$$ $$10^{30}+8\ 674\ 434\ 297$$ $$10^{30}+88\ 929\ 159\ 177$$

Comment: @Peter: In maths, as you know, there are a lot of extraordinary facts and the conjecture you quote is without any doubt one of them in case be true.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may have definite crossover properties with a [conjecture I floated a while back](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479074/conjecture-all-x21-primes-for-x90-can-be-represented-as-the-sum-of-five), that all primes of the form $x^2+1$ (for $x>90$) can be represented as the sum of five smaller such primes.

It seemed likely true in my case, so I would be surprised if your conjecture didn't turn out to be likely true as well.